Flutter draw line with custom pattern in Map
Is it possible to draw a line in Flutter with a complete custom pattern that repeats itself along the line? For example, I want to have this pattern:

So if I draw a straight line, it should like like this:

Now, I don't just want to draw straight lines. I actually want to draw polylines on a map. I am using the flutter_map package. I saw that the PolylineLayer Widget just uses a CustomPainter to draw the lines along the map. The Polilines are not very customizable (they just come with options for a border, dashes, etc). So my idea is to just create another widget that does exactly the same as the PolylineLayer widget, but with my own CustomPainter, that should draw the custom pattern along the path. Ideally I could just create an svg with the pattern and apply it to the path, if that is possible.
Edit
I tried pskinks Answer. It generally works, but it doesn't quite work for a curved line. Here is my code:
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var path = ui.Path();
    final paint = Paint()
    ..strokeWidth = polyline.strokeWidth
    ..strokeCap = polyline.strokeCap
    ..strokeJoin = polyline.strokeJoin
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..shader = ImageShader(
      polyline.image, // this is a ui.Image
      TileMode.repeated,
      TileMode.repeated,
      Matrix4.identity().storage,
    );
    
    final offsets = getOffsets(polyline.points);
    _paintLine(path, offsets);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}



void _paintLine(ui.Path path, List<Offset> offsets) {
  if (offsets.isEmpty) {
    return;
  }
  path.addPolygon(offsets, false);
}

List<Offset> getOffsets(List<LatLng> points) {
   // Calculate offsets on map
}

Now, the line is drawn, the path is correct, and the line has the pattern of the image. But the direction of the image doesn't follow the line.
The image that I use for the pattern looks like this:

The outcome I expect should look somewhat like this. This is just an example to visualize that the image direction should follow the line. It should be even more curved in reality:

The current outcome looks somewhat like this. I hope it makes the problem clear. The direction does not follow the line:

This is what it actually looks like in my app (to visualize it again):

Edit 2
I to draw each line individually with composeMatrix as mentioned by pskink. The patterns get rotated, but I can't seem to figure out the strokeWidth and translation. The height of my image should stretch exactly across the height of the line. The width of my image should not stretch, instead it should repeat. Here is my code, and below is the current outcome.
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (final polyline in polylines) {
      final offsets = getOffsets(polyline.points);
      if (offsets.isEmpty) {
        continue;
      }

      final image = _cacheManager.getImageSync(polyline.svgPath);

      final paint = Paint()
        ..strokeWidth = polyline.strokeWidth
        ..strokeCap = polyline.strokeCap
        ..strokeJoin = polyline.strokeJoin
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

      for (int i = 0; i < offsets.length - 1; i++) {
        final p1 = offsets[i];
        final p2 = offsets[i + 1];
        final angle = (p2 - p1).direction;
        final center = Offset((p1.dx + p2.dx) / 2, (p1.dy + p2.dy) / 2);

        final matrix = composeMatrix(
          anchor: center,
          rotation: angle,
          scale: polyline.strokeWidth / image.height,
          translate: p1,
        );

        final shader = ImageShader(
          image,
          TileMode.repeated,
          TileMode.repeated,
          matrix.storage,
        );

        paint.shader = shader;

        final path = ui.Path()
          ..moveTo(p1.dx, p1.dy)
          ..lineTo(p2.dx, p2.dy);

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant SvgPolylinePainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.bounds != bounds ||
        oldDelegate.polylines.length != polylines.length ||
        oldDelegate.hash != hash;
  }
}



yes, with CustomPainter you can use Paint.shader with ImageShader

@pskink Thank for your suggestion! I tried it and it generally works, but not exactly as I want to. I edited my question to summarize the problem

you should draw line by line then, you have two options: 1) for each line create a shader with a different, rotated / translated matrix or 2) for each line rotate / translate the whole canvas (either by calling Canvas.rotate with Canvas.translate or Canvas.transform)

Could you maybe give me a code example? I've been trying like that and I get the right angle, but somehow the lines still look messed up and not very clean.

something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64758628/rotate-painted-text-about-its-center/64772650#64772650 - most likely you just need one Canvas.translate, not two, also you can use handy function like composeMatrix

indeed composeMatrix would be better as it can be used either with ImageShader (case 1) or Canvas.transform (case 2)

I tried that solution. I am definitely getting closer. But it is not 100% as I want it yet. I edited my question again with my code and the outcome. Do you know what I have to fix there?

this one is better: https://pastebin.com/zNCQajtB, again check if paintLines1() or paintLines2() is faster for large number of lines

btw, i completely forgot that you can also use drawAtlas that could be faster that multiple drawLine calls as it is called only once to draw multiple images - you would need to check it out how it works in your case

drawAtlas docs say: "Draws many parts of an image - the atlas - onto the canvas.
This method allows for optimization when you want to draw many parts of an image onto the canvas, such as when using sprites or zooming. It is more efficient than using multiple calls to drawImageRect and provides more functionality to individually transform each image part by a separate rotation or scale and blend or modulate those parts with a solid color.
